# VSCode not detecting java paths in tycho-pomless projects

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, tycho

I have been assigned to a project that builds some Eclipse plugins. There is a root `pom.xml`, and maven builds it successfully. But when I load it into VSCode, with the Java Pack (`vscjava.vscode-java-pack`) loaded, and load the Java projects, many files produce errors like

```
The declared package "com.correct.package" does not match the expected package ""
```

and

```
The import com.something cannot be resolved
```

even though maven just built the packages just fine.

Now the obvious reason why it might not work is that the [tycho-pomless](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/pomless) extension is installed and most of the sub-packages only have `.project`, `build.properties` and `plugin.xml`, but no `pom.xml`.

Is it possible to generate all the `pom.xml`s or something else that the VSCode plugin would understand to set the correct package roots and classpaths?

Comment: Can you share the project in github for me to reproduce the error?

Comment: @MollyWang, unfortunately no, and I don't understand the thing enough to create a minimal example. But it turns out Eclipse has some problems with the references as well, so I'll have to try again once it actually works at least there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the folder which contains the folder `com` and choose **Add Folder to Java Source Path**. Try this and see if the question goes away.

Comment: I am no longer seeing the first kind of errors. The "Import Java Projects Into Workspace" seems to have worked better second time around. Now I am just seeing many unresolved imports—which I am actually seeing also when I try to open the project in Eclipse. I tried adding `"/home/user/.m2/repository/**/*.jar"` into `"java.project.referencedLibraries"` (I am opening it with devcontainer, so home is fixed), but it didn't help. Or didn't yet take effect.

Comment: If dependencies can be found in maven repository, you can manually readd them:  Open Command Palette--> Maven: Add a dependency, then type name and add to project. If jars are official accessible, try to download locally and add to referenced libaries.

Comment: I can't add them through maven, because they are tycho projects. They have `.project` and `.classpath` and the `tycho-pomless` maven extension creates maven build files from them just for the duration of the maven execution. The language server is derived from Eclipse code, and understands those as well, but the dependencies are missing. *And they are missing even if I open it in Eclipse*, because the things are Eclipse plugins and reference them in some other way. The tycho-pomless extension can find them, apparently, but I have no idea where.

Comment: @JanHudec. so, we can say the error is not related to java extension pack cause even in eclipse, the error still exists. you may open an issue in github for more help. and thanks for your marking my answer. :)

Comment: Well, there was initially error that some of the projects were not found, but that disappeared on it's own (and I think your answer would work if it didn't). And then there is the fact that the projects themselves are weird, but that's something else.